# confidence interval proportion

Tags: probability, parameter-estimation

**Question:**

---

A random sample of $170$ boys from $8502$ boys in an area showed 
that $21$ had some nutritional deficiency. Give confidence interval , proportion of nutritionally deficient boys and standard error of estimate .

Here , $P’ = \frac nx = \frac {21}{170}$

$Q’ = 1-p’ = \frac {170-21}{170}$

But as per proportion formula : 
$P'\pm Z_{ (\frac{\alpha}2)}*  \sqrt{(\frac{P'Q'}N)}$

In this question there is no confidence interval because of which I am unable to find the value of $Z_{(\frac {\alpha}2)}$    . Please suggest how to proceed hereafter. I am stuck.

Comment: No % is specifically asked for, so why not give a 95% CI?

Comment: You mean , assume .95 as cc and solve it ? Will do if such assumptions are permissible in such questions because i am not able to think of any other alternative as well. I don't have the answer handy to it , so i am not too sure. Thanks for suggesting , David.

Comment: It's odd that they don't specify. 95% is standard, but 90% and 99% are frequently required. Maybe you could give them all three? :D

Comment: great idea . will do. thanks again